# Can tidesdk work with symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, url-rewriting, desktop-application, tidesdk

May I ask if anyone has ever been deployed a SF2 project and if not, do you think it's possible ?

Actually I can't understand if tidesdk handles URL rewritting, as it's a key concept of symfony. All my attempts ended in a php exception (The stream or file /symfotest/sf2/app/logs/dev.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied).

Thanks

Comment: chmod -R 777 app/logs

Comment: Sure I did but apparently chmodding has no effect. Maybe the issue is coming from tidesdk, can we set the folders into which tidesk has permission to write files (not Apache) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from the developers:

> TideKit includes Zend as part of our PHP but we don't encourage full
>   blown PHP app development since this can limit capabilities and
>   platforms for deployment. Therefore, we've not looked at frameworks
>   like Symphony, CodeIgniter, and others to ensure the y can be used.
>
> Foremost, TideKit is a JS Platform that enables you to consistently
>   write your code once in a single language. With more than 100,000
>   packages of functionality available in JavaScript, there is not much
>   you cannot find these days (as opposed to write yourself). Together
>   with our native capabilities, TideKit is suitable for virtually
>   anything you can imagine for HTML5, hybrid, or native apps.
>
> We are currently working on our demos to provide a glimpse of
>   TideKit's capabilities. TideKit is very flexible to work with and
>   we'll be demonstrating app work flows that mean fast and enjoyable
>   development.